# German job seeker with 4years of experience

Tags: germany, indian-citizens, employment, job-hunting, german-citizens

I have a masters degree from a German university in mechatronics plus 4 years of similar field experience. I am planning on going back to Germany but I am a bit skeptical if my job seeker visa will be approved as I am falling short on job experience.

Comment: Welcome to Expatriates. What is your question exactly?

Comment: A master degree is sufficient. Job experience is needed if you don't have a degree.

Comment: The tase are confusing - are you a citizen of India or Germany?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most important is your university degree. Your job expierence is not that important and not part of the requirements for getting a job seeker visa. Check out the web page of the German embassy in your country. Looking for long-term (more than 90 days) D- or National Visa and have a look for their checklist of applying for a job seeker visa!